# Fourier series of $f(x)=\pi -x$ for $x \in [0,2\pi]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \pi -x, \quad0<x<2\pi\\  0, \quad x=0,x=2\pi\end{cases}$$

I need to find the Fourier Series of $$f(x)=\pi -x, \quad x \in [0,2\pi].$$
First, we can expand the function in a $2\pi$-periodic defined on $\mathbb{R}$

**The theory in my textbook is:**

For a Reimann-integrable function $f:[-\pi,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The Fourier series of f is:
$$ S[f](x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_kcos(kx)+b_ksin(kx))$$
where
$$ a_k=a_k(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(kx)dx, \quad k=0,1,2, \dots$$
and
$$ b_k=b_k(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)sin(kx)dx, \quad k=1,2, \dots$$

Now for $f(x)=\pi -x, \quad x \in [0,2\pi].$

**My understanding** is that i have to "transform" the function to be defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$ for my theory to work. But i can't see how i can do that.

**Hint of the exercise:** Make the function odd (symmetric around $0$).
**Solution:**$$ S[f](x)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(kx)}{k}$$

Sf=\frac{a_0}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_kcos(kx)+b_ksin(kx))

**Edit after answers in comments**

We transform the original function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \pi -x, \quad0<x<\pi\\  -x-\pi, \quad -\pi<x<0\end{cases}$$

The new function is odd so:
$$a_k=0$$
and
$$ b_k=b_k(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)sin(kx)dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\pi-x)sin(kx)dx= \dots = \frac{2}{k}$$

So we have the result we wanted.

**But** the original function does not have the same graph as transformed one. 
Is this a problem?

Comment: Have you tried solving for $a_k$?

Comment: I understand that first i have to "define" $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ to compute $a_k$ and $b_k$.

Comment: So you don't need to worry about things like this. If $f:[0,L]\to\mathbb R$, then $f$ has fourier coefficients given by $$\hat f(k) = \frac{1}{L}\int^{L}_0 f(x)e^{-2ik\pi x/L}\,dx$$ and so the fourier series is $$f(x) \sim \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f(k)e^{2ik\pi x}$$

Comment: Alright, i haven't seen the complex Fourier series yet, So what i understand is that it doesn't matter in which domain the function is defined as long as it has $2\pi$ length

Comment: Yes. Also, it's just a different notation so do not be intimidated. I would try to learn the notation, however. It makes things much simpler.

Comment: Oops, there is a typo. The complex exponential should read $$f(x) \sim \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f(k)e^{2ik\pi x/L}$$

Comment: Length $2\pi$ is the most convenient, but one can work with arbitrary length $L$, as the formula suggests.

Comment: If i "transform" the function for the computation to be simpler ( in this case to make it odd for $a_k=0$, does the first function has to have the same graph as the transformed one?

Comment: The integration is an easy integration by parts, writing $\cos(kx)=\frac{(\sin(kx))^{\prime}}{k}$

Comment: @AndrewZhang See my edit, i think i got it right

Comment: The result is correct but there is no need to "transform" the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $f(x)$ for $-\pi < x <0$ should be $\pi - (x+2\pi) = -\pi-x$ is already correct. Because you want $y$ to be the same as $\pi -x$ on $(\pi, 2\pi)$, but shifted $2\pi$ to the left to be on $(-\pi, 0)$.

Using your textbook's version of Fourier series, then the Fourier series is $2\pi$ periodic. So plotting your series using your computed coefficients $a_{k}$ and $b_{k}$, but for $x \in (0, 2\pi)$ will give the same as the original one. But if you plot the Fourier series on $(-\pi, \pi)$, of course it will be different. To give better understanding, try plot it from $(-10\pi, 10\pi)$ you will see repeated patterns.

Example of Periodic Extension capability of Fourier series (*img from Wikipedia):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FourierSeries means using【sum of complex exponential functions, like $e^{j n\omega x},\quad n\in \mathbb{Z},\omega\in \mathbb{R},x\in \mathbb{R} $】 (one form is $\sum\limits_{n}e^{j n\omega x}$) to approximate a periodic function(here the periodic function can even be a function which transforms a RealNumber to a ComplexNumber).

**I don't know what the periodic function here is, so I guessed one.**
In my figure, their periods are both $2\pi$

[image]

```
f = UnitStep[x]*(Pi - x) + UnitStep[-x]*(-x - Pi);
g = FourierSeries[f, x, 10]
ExpToTrig[g]
Plot[{g, f}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {"g", "f"}]
(* They are both periodic function actually, but I only plot them in \
[-2Pi,2Pi]*)
```